# brew install python - XCode not installed

Tags: python, xcode, macos, homebrew

I just moved from macports to homebrew. I cleaned my environment prior to installing homebrew and removed everything thats get installed in opts.

Now I got the following:

```
$brew install python
Warning: Xcode not installed
Most stuff needs Xcode to build: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/
Warning: python-2.7.5 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I have edited my bash_profile

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/share/python
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PYTHONPATH:$PATH
```

I also have installed xcode & I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8, what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the xcode command line tools installed? I believe they are required for many things

Comment: @Kevin I have xcode install I am running xcode 3.2 the documentations thats out there are different for 4.0 upwards so i dont' get a update screen like in version 4.

Comment: looks like there are no command line tools for 10.6.8